# Testing for a non-null pointer, and returning null otherwise

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value

I'm wondering whether it's considered okay to do something like this.

```
if ( p_Pointer != NULL ) {
  return p_Pointer;
} else {
  return NULL;
}
```

Without the else, whatever. The point is that if the pointer is null, NULL is going to be returned, so it would seem pointless wasting a step on this. However, it seems useful for debugging purposes, because if I was stepping through with a debugger I would be able to check with this test if the pointer is NULL or not.

Any comments or suggestions regarding this practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's "okay" to do this, i.e. there's nothing wrong with it, although it's not very useful. If you're stepping through in a debugger, you should be able to display the value of p_Pointer anyway.

It's similar to

```
if( flag == TRUE ) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

rather than just `return flag;`

Comment: Its also equivalent to if (a > 5) return true; else return false;

Answer (score 6):

You could just say:

```
return p_Pointer;
```

Because the `if statement` is superfluous in that case.

Comment: @Anon: And you could also use the "Watch" feature of your debugger to check if the pointer is NULL or not.

Comment: I agree. You don't want to clutter the code with a pointless check.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, it *looks* really weird. If you actually do more, or it the expression is used regularly, then that would dispel suspicions.

With a little more, it is not so unusual:

```
    if ( p_Pointer != NULL ) {
      return p_Pointer;
    } else {
      assert(p_Pointer);
      return NULL;
    }
```

or

```
    assert(p_Pointer);
    return p_Pointer;
```

oder vielleicht:

```
    return require_valid_pointer(p_Pointer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional breakpoint (on the would-be single "return" line) instead?